# Can't find Faendal Skyrim Remastered

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I told him it's time to part ways when I was working with the Grey Beards but now I went to re recruit him and I cannot find him. I'm nervous that he died on his way home - can that happen or do I just need to wait a while? He has all my good loot that I didn't want to carry, so I really need to find him.

Comment: Are you looking around Riverwood? It's possible that he died on the way home, but unlikely. I've sent him home dozens of times without an issue.

Answer (score 2):

### Where Do I Find Him?

Faendal lives at the town of Riverwood, so try going to Riverwood. Normally he's seen carrying wood back and fourth near the lumber mill, or even at his house (near the back of the town, near Ralof's friend's house).

If you can't find him, wait for a few hours/days and he might appear.

### Did He Die On The Way Home?

The fact that he died on his way home is false, due to game chunks (the only exception is if you were at the location where Faendal is getting killed, but you said you looked in Riverwood and you were at High Hrothgar.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the possibility of Faendal dying is completely out of the question... the exterior cells for High Hrothgar are pretty large, and he could have died as soon as he started down the mountain (or fell off) without the player noticing. I agree with the suggestion to wait for a while -- that's worked for me in the past when I've had trouble finding him.

Comment: @pushasha what do you mean? We don't know where the player was right after Faendal left. Perhaps the player was still in High Hrothgar talking to the Greybeards, since he said he was working with the Greybeards. He might be going outside, but most likely, Faendal is gone due to chunks.

Comment: You're right -- we don't know where he was. That's why I said it's not something to completely rule out. He didn't say he was in the interior cells of High Hrothgar, so he could have been outside for all we know. Perhaps the part of the game where the graybeards help you learn Whirlwind Sprint? I'm not saying that your answer is wrong, I'm just saying not to rule out the possibility without further details from the asker.

Comment: @pushasha it's possible, of course, but most likely not.

Comment: Glad we agree. I only responded with that comment, because the wording of your answer suggested (at least to me) that such an occurrence was impossible.

Answer (score 1):

One should be aware that Faendal's commute between home and work is, to say the least, "scenic".  I frequently find him on the path in the hills south of town.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow this page:
https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/615805-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/answers/300694-what-is-the-console-command-for-moving-an-npc-to-you-or-you-to-it
and this page to find his code:
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Faendal

then press the key to the left of the 1 (<kbd>`</kbd>) to open the in-game console.
Press the (`) key, then type
prid 0001348c (then the ENTER key)
resurrect (then the ENTER key)
(which should now give you some letters and numbers)
then type
player.moveto 0001348c (then the ENTER key). to bring him to you.  If he's dead, you may have to enter "resurrect 0001348C".